# Watchdog timer on PLC

Tags: watchdog, plc, modbus

I've currently set my PLC as a Modbus server, and written some Python code which connects to it and acts as a Modbus client.

I am having some problems with the Modbus server sometimes terminating the PLC, when the Python code requests/sends information to the server.

It terminates by showing a popup window saying:

`runtime error #16 (watchdog expired Task = default task)`

And then an error message which it terminates with is:

```
IEC Task 0 ' cycle time is greater than the set watchdog timer; or cycle time exceeded, but shorter than watchdog timers
```

The only code I am running on the PLC is basically

```
(*Bit0 := TRUE;*)
(*Bit1 := TRUE;*)
(*Bit2 := TRUE;*)

DO1 := Bit0; (* Start/Stop *)
DO2 := Bit1; (* Direction [False - Reverse ; True - Forward] *)
DO3 := Bit2; (* Speed [Fast = 11; Medium = 10; Slow = 01 ; Stop = 00] *)
DO4 := Bit3; (* Speed [Fast = 11; Medium = 10; Slow = 01 ; Stop = 00] *)
```

and that's it. `Bitx` are coil address's and `DOx` are digital outputs on the PLC.

I guess, based on the error message, it has something to do with the watchdog. I haven't manually changed anything with the watchdog, or even set it.
How do I configure it in codesys?

Should I maybe adjust some of these values?

[image]

Comment: Please use proper punctuation\capitalization, it makes you look educated.

Comment: .... Better?... Is anything unclear?

Comment: Which PLC are you using?

Comment: PLC using is a ABB PM554

Comment: Have you tried increasing the "Task timeout" value?

Comment: by how much.. I tried doubling it, ended up with the same result